# Is it possible to return a Django.model instance with htmx?

Tags: django, http-post, htmx

I'm using django with django-htmx. I want to use hx-vals to return an instance that was given by the context to the django template.

```html
{% for auszubildender in auszubildende %}
                
                 
             <div 
             hx-post="/htmxFunctions/azubiAnzeigen" 
             hx-trigger="click" 
             hx-target="#content"
             hx-vals='{ "test": "test", "auszubildender": "{{auszubildender}}"}'>
                       
                  {% if auszubildender.first_name  %}
                  [...]
                  {% endif %}
              </div>

{% endfor %}
```

When I'm accesing *auszubildender* with `request.POST.get("auszubildender")` it returns a **str** (the username as auszubildender is a django default Usermodel).
Is there a way to post / get the instance or will a POST method always return just a string? In this case I will just use the PK to access the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST query data don't return objects, but string values. Best way for you would be to pass the pk as you mentioned.